# How do I include a license file when when doing an ASP.net core build and publish in an Azure Devops Pipeline?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, azure-devops

In my .net core 5.0 webapp, I have a file license.dat, which enables use of a paid component. In visual studio, the file is set to "COPY ALWAYS" for "Copy to Output Directory".

If I build and run my project locally in Visual Studio - or publish it locally to a folder - the file is included in the output.

If I run ´dotnet publish´ locally, the file is also included in the output.

However, when using an Azure Devops pipeline, the file is left out of the build artefact.

How can I make sure the file is included in the build artefact produced by the Azure build pipeline?

Comment: Please include the snippet/screenshot of your build pipeline tasks/configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Copy Files task in Azure build pipeline. you need to add new task copy file and set the source and destination folder. This is how to do using azure classic build pipeline.

- How to add new copy task

[image]

- copy task settings

[image]